# My list session is not retriving the right value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a list to save the orders the client had selected and i wanted to pass the values on the list to other page so i was trying to use

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["list"] = MySelected;
```

but I am not getting the values in my other page.

order page:

```
protected void ButtonCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string MyPkList = string.Join(",", MySelected);    
    SqlCommand cmdSQLCount = new SqlCommand("select Count(*) from [EncomendaTEMP] where No_ IN(" + MyPkList + ")", con);
        cmdSQLCount.Connection.Open();
        int qtd = 0;
        SqlDataReader reader = cmdSQLCount.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
            qtd = reader.GetInt32(0);
        if (qtd > 0)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["list"] = MySelected;
            Response.Redirect("Booking.aspx", false);                
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<h2> Nenhum registo encontrado! </h2>");
        }
```

Booking page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var list = HttpContext.Current.Session["list"];
     Response.Write("<h2> PK = "+list+" </h2>");
}
```

returns:
[image]

Comment: What do you get in the `list` variable?

Comment: i putted an image of what it returns

Comment: `.toString()` is what you need. `var list = HttpContext.Current.Session["list"].ToString();`

Comment: You can NOT simple convert list to a string... list is a collection so you need to loop thru it to access the items inside the list....

Comment: @शेखर the return is the same with the .tostring

Comment: `var list = HttpContext.Current.Session["list"] as List<string>; string items = string.Join(",", list);`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya and with that i loop the string items ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya ohh thats exactly what i wanted, thank you man :)

Comment: use parameterize query you code is prone to sql injection.

Comment: @शेखर and how do i do that?

Comment: Here is simple example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/why-should-always-use-the-parameterized-query-to-avoid-sql-i/

Comment: Please don't put "Solved" in your title. If your question has an answer, post the answer as an answer then accept it (if nobody else posts a better answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get join value of element in `List<string>`, try:

```
var list = HttpContext.Current.Session["list"] as List<string>; 
string items = string.Join(",", list);
```

from @Chetan Ranpariya 's comment.